# QGIS 2.16 Extract Nodes command works strange

Tags: qgis, extract, feature-extraction, qgis-2.16, nodes

On Qgis 2.16 when I am using the extract nodes command, even when I save to file with a specific name, the result is a layer named "Nodes" with the extracted points. I have to go to the folder where I saved the .shp file and load it in the program. It is not a major problem, it is somehow annoying. Do you have the same experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the settings under `Processing Options -> General` to activate `Use file names as layer name` as you can see below, then it will use the file name as you save it in your directory.

[image]